# is there a simple class/library which uses pyQT/webkit to scrape websites with javascript support?

Tags: python, webkit, pyqt, web-scraping

i'm looking at using pyQT to scrape websites with javascript support, after dabbling with all the static html alternatives (beautifulsoup, mechanize etc.)

clearly pyQT is a much more generic tool and as such is not optimised for my needs.

is there any classes/libraries which give me simple functions for using pyQT for relatively simple scraping duties?

i have found a few classes/scripts by searching google, but am hopefull for something better suited to my needs!

i need to submit forms, maintain sessions, and return the html for processing with lxml.

thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I use ruby's watir (browser automation that works across multiple browsers and OS) for my web scraping needs. For almost everything else, I use python.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [spynner](http://code.google.com/p/spynner/)--it's a programmatic browser module based on QtWebKit. It might meet your needs.